# Where does the intrusive R come from in “warsh”?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, rhoticity, intrusive-r, pennsylvanian-english

My grandmother, who grew up in western Pennsylvania, pronounced *wash* and *Washington* with an [intrusive R](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110227/non-rhotic-dialects-and-intrusive-r): “warsh” and “Warshington.” Where does the intrusive R come from in that dialect? It doesn’t seem to be produced by the same mechanism that changes *law and order* to “lawr and order” in non-rhotic dialects (plus, my grandmother’s dialect was rhotic, if I recall correctly).

Comment: Would this be the same R that makes an _arse_ out of _ass_?

Comment: @terdon Nope, [*arse* and *ass*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/is-there-a-difference-between-arse-and-ass) surprisingly have different etymology to explain the difference!

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't recall my grandmother using intrusive R in words like *law* and *idea,* just *wash.* But she’s been gone for several years, so I can’t double check.

Comment: @terdon Or even mainstream “mispronunciation” like *iron/iorn.* I'll never understand why people get upset over things like *ask/aks* (which actually has legit English etymology) while maintaining a blind spot for words like *iron/iorn.*

Comment: My grandmother (born and raised on Prince Edward Island) used 'warsh.' Lots of Scottish/Irish immigrants settled in that area.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to John Kelly of the Washington Post ([Catching the Sounds of the City](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A62786-2004Oct25.html)), he claims:

> "warsh" is the predominant characteristic of what linguists call America's midland accent. The accent can be found in the swath of the country that extends west from Washington, taking in Maryland; southern Pennsylvania; West Virginia; parts of Virginia; southern Ohio, Indiana and Illinois; most of Missouri; and Kentucky, Tennessee, Arkansas, Oklahoma, much of Kansas and west Texas.

With the help of [Barbara Johnstone, of Carnegie Mellon University](http://www.cmu.edu/hss/english/people/faculty/bios/barbara-johnstone.html), he traces it back to Scotch-Irish immigrants at least a couple hundred years ago.

Midland English is described as "firmly rhotic", where [rhotic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rhotic)* (of or pertaining to a dialect of English in which the r  is pronounced at the end of a syllable or before a consonant).

Barbara Johnstone, in an interview covered by the article [Steel Speak](http://www.pbs.org/speak/seatosea/americanvarieties/pittsburghese/) said this:

> But some features of the accent of southwestern Pennsylvania are geographically distributed in the same way—in the Pittsburgh area and to the west and the south— as are words and grammatical structures we know are Scotch-Irish in origin. This suggests that these may be older features that spread with the early settlers. One of these is the use of an r sound in the word wash, so that it sounds something like worsh.

(There's lots more linguistic trivia in that interview, and I think you'll find it interesting.)

*You may recall my mentioning *rhoticity* in reference to [Why do British Singers Sound American?](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/explainer/2012/11/skyfall_theme_song_by_adele_why_do_british_singers_sound_american.html) in response to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157416/term-for-phonological-elements-of-a-dialect/157428#157428). In that article, the author states that most dialects of England *drop* their Rs. Go figure, but that's not Scotch-Irish either.

Comment: Do we have any independent confirmation that *"warsh"* was used in Scotch-Irish?

Comment: [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ONC0AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA153&dq=warshing&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6qQzU8anKPSosQT2rICoCQ&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCDgo#v=onepage&q=warshing&f=false) we have an 19th-century sighting of *warsh* in the wilds of West Somersetshire, which is quite far from Scotland or Ireland.

Comment: Very interesting! Is there any information about precursors or cousins to this quirk that would help illustrate the mechanism? I never noticed a similar quirk in words other than *wash,* which makes me wonder whether it's an etymological (word) thing rather than a linguistic (phonetic shift) thing.

Comment: And [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=qHkKAAAAIAAJ&pg=PR29&dq=warsh&hl=en&sa=X&ei=naYzU5zqOJe-sQSsyYDYAw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=warsh&f=false) is another *"warsh"* from West Somerset. It might be a past linguistic quirk which has only left one trace on the language, kind of like the former dialectical variant British pronunciation of *"er"*, which has persisted in England in *clerk* and *Berkeley*, but appears only in *sergeant* in the U.S. The two references I found contain pretty good descriptions of the West Somerset dialect, so you might figure it out by reading them.

Comment: @Bradd Szonye - I'm not exposed to it frequently in California to be all that aware of other similar instances. One old friend always got my attention when he habitually pronounced Hawaii as How-Are-Ya. Unfortunately, he's gone, so I can't ask him where he got that from.

Comment: From the second of my links: "Also in all words having *ash* in them, *r* is inserted. As arshen-tree, arshes, warsh, larsh, splarsh, marsh, &c."

Comment: @PeterShor - You may have something there. I may send an email off to Prof. Johnstone and ask her about it. She seems to be pretty enthusiastic about the subject, so maybe I'll receive a reply. If I do that' I'll also ask her about independent research from hers that addresses this. If I hear form her, I'll post it here.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks! I don't recall Nana inserting Rs into other words like that, so I think the feature may have been less ubiquitous in the dialect variant in her home town (Washington, PA, amusingly enough).

Comment: @PeterShor Turns out my fiancé’s West Texas family says *warsh* too, but apparently nothing like *splarsh.* I wonder if that's because the vowel sound differs between Somerset and the Midlands? Splash and wash don't rhyme here.

Comment: @Bradd: I'm not sure whether they rhymed in Somerset, either; I suspect they did, but I would have to look at the links more carefully to decide. But 'r' got interpolated between "a" and "ʃ" for at least two different kinds of 'a's: it was put after the "a" in words ending in "-ation" and in words rhyming with "splash".

Comment: @PeterShor - Dr. Johnstone replied with a less certain answer about Scotch-Irish origin than the cites I gave above would indicate. She referred me to a colleague, Dr. Michael Montgomery. I'll update if I hear from him.

Comment: Barbara Johnstone is a former student of mine at the University of Michigan, and currently she knows more about English in Pennsylvania than anybody else. FWIW, I grew up (in DeKalb, IL) saying /worʃ, worʃklɔθ, worʃɪŋ/, and /worʃɪŋtən/. As well as /ɡarʃ/ 'gosh', the interjection, which hasn't been mentioned here yet. No other intrusive /r/'s.

Comment: Just saw a video from the 70s of Donald Segretti testifying presumably in front of a congressional committee: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W_k_EXlqgvg), and he said "Warshington." I don't know where he grew up, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Segretti) seems to suggest California.

Answer (score 2):

Warsh was used frequently in Quyon and Mayo, West Quebec for at least two generations of Irish Canadians. My father and his siblings spoke what I though was simply bad English, however I now realize that it was an accent transported from Ireland (a la The Great Famine). They also said 'he's an arse', 'Warshington' and 'that'd be a fine how-do-you-do'. Clear, useful and to the point. I hope that dialect is still alive and kicking arse somewhere !