# Is this intrusive r? "Arya Stark" pronounced as "Aryer Stark"

Tags: british-english, phonology, phonetics, intrusive-r

In Game of Thrones, season 4, ep.8 around 37:50, The Hound says:

> [...]and his travelling companion Arya Stark.

He pronounces it like "Aryer Stark". It seems to be a similar concept as an intrusive r, but here the /r/ sound is followed by a consonant.

Could someone share any insight of whether this is a rule, or maybe a question of accent or something else?

Comment: [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R) *The phenomenon of intrusive R is an overgeneralizing reinterpretation of linking R into an r-insertion rule that affects any word that ends in the non-high vowels /ə/, /ɪə/, /ɑː/, or /ɔː/; **when such a word is closely followed by another word beginning in a vowel sound,** an /r/ is inserted between them, even when no  final /r/ was historically present.* "**Stark**" doesn't begin with a vowel sound.

Comment: One thing to consider about this particular example is that the actor who play The Hound, Rory McCann, naturally speaks with a Scottish accent, but is using some other accent in this role.

Comment: @Juhaxz: Exactly. This is a mistake made by a rhotic speaker trying to talk with a non-rhotic accent. A native non-rhotic speaker of English would say *Arya Stark*.

Answer (score -1):

This is an extreme case of intrusive r; it is not at all typical of intrusive r.

> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R))  The phenomenon of intrusive R is an overgeneralizing reinterpretation of linking R into an r-insertion rule that affects any word that ends in the non-high vowels /ə/, /ɪə/, /ɑː/, or /ɔː/; when such a word is closely followed by another word beginning in a vowel sound, an /r/ is inserted between them, even when no final /r/ was historically present. For example, the phrase *bacteria in it* would be pronounced /bækˈtɪəriərˌɪnɪt/. The epenthetic /r/ can be inserted to prevent hiatus (two consecutive vowel sounds).
>
> In extreme cases an intrusive R can follow a reduced schwa, such as for the example *if you hafta[r], I’ll help* and in the following examples taken from the native speech of English speakers from Eastern Massachusetts: *I’m gonna[r]ask Adrian, t[ər]add to his troubles, a lotta[r]apples and the[r]apples*. A related phenomenon involves the dropping of a consonant at the juncture of two words and the insertion of an r in its place, sometimes this occurs in conjunction with the reduction of the final vowel in the first word to a schwa: examples of this are *He shoulda[r]eaten and I saw[r]’m (for I saw them)*

Comment: Am I missing something? Is "intrusive r" even possible at all before a consonant? (in OP's case, the consonant *cluster* ***st***).

Comment: I agree with your statement, but I don't think this reference describes the case of "Arya[r]Stark".  All the cases described there, even the extreme ones, still have the *r* intruding between two vowel sounds.  This example seems similar to, but not quite the same as the "r-insertion" you'll rarely hear in some American English accents: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531737/am-i-imagining-the-warshington-washington-accent/531738#531738

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my opinion this is the same context as indicated in the second part of the reference ("In extreme cases…"): the comma indicates a break in the flow, so does a following syllable that begins with a consonant. This type of intrusion is not typical because it is in no way induced by a pseudo r-liaison. Personnally, I wouldn't classify it a being r-intrusion (merely spurious pronunciation).

Comment: @Juhasz Yes, all are followed by a vowel, except the first, where a comma is equivalent to a following consonant for the flow.

Comment: Well, I've always been under the impression intrusive r is primarily a *British* thing. I can't begin to imagine a Brit introducing an extra r before Stark. I can *almost* imagine an extremely rhotic drawling American doing something like that, but it simply doesn't feel like the same linguistic phenomenon to me.

Comment: Google won't tell me the actual url, but if I search for **pronounce arya stark** the first snippet returned on google home page tells me that in *British* English it's **aa·yuh staak** (no **r**'s at all), and in American English it's **aa·ree·uh staark** (even with those two extra **r**'s, there isn't one immediately before ***Stark***).

Comment: I could imagine an actor with a rhotic accent trying to *imitate* a non-rhotic one might end up with something like this. Is the actor American?

Comment: @alphabet, the actor is Scottish but seemingly attempting some kind of English accent.

Comment: I think Wikipedia doesn't really know what it's talking about here. I live in Eastern Massachusetts, and I used to hear intrusive 'r's quite often (they're getting rarer); *I sawr em* is very common in this accent, *a lotter apples* is perfectly normal, but *the rapples* sounds really weird.

Comment: @PeterShor: Imho, *the rapples* sounds weird because it's actually *the[e] **yapples*** :)

Comment: @PeterShor Probly because r-insertion only happens after non-high vowels. *The* ends in a high vowel before another vowel.