# Why does the 'Intrusive 'R' appear in the state of Mississippi?

Tags: british-english, dialects, southern-white-vernacular-english, intrusive-r

I've seen people discuss the intrusive 'R'. I have also been very curious about this subject, because I am from Mississippi and both my Mother and my Grandmother use the intrusive 'R'. ('Warsh', instead of 'Wash'). I know they came from the hill country of Mississippi (the northeastern corner (Tishomingo) of Mississippi) and my Mother is 50% Scottish.
My question: Is anyone aware that this intrusive 'R' extends all the way to Mississippi?
Thank You.

Comment: [Related and possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160117/where-does-the-intrusive-r-come-from-in-warsh#comment540149_160119). The R in *gosh, wash, washing, Washington, washcloth* is probably not the same as what's normally referred to as intrusive-R such as in *lore and order* or *the very idear of it*.

Comment: @tchrist You've finally explained something from Popeye I've had lying dormant for decades.'Gorsh, ....'

Comment: Yes, this is the Midlands pronunciation of (in my idiolect -- I was born in 1942 in DeKalb, IL) "warsh, warshing, Warshington, garsh!" and that's all. It **is** an /r/ and it **is** intrusive, but it's not the same "intrusive r" one gets in the non-rhotic northeastern dialects. Southern dialects are a different kettle of fish entirely, and I don't know diddly about them.